# X has 29 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 30 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I am trying to code a machine-learning model that predicts breast cancer using the `RandomForestClassifier`. Code shown below:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
print("Shape of training set:", x_train.shape)
print("Shape of test set:", x_test.shape)
```

Shape of training set: (292, 30)

The shape of the test set is: (91, 29)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
ss = StandardScaler()
X_train = ss.fit_transform(x_train)
X_test = ss.fit_transform(x_test)
```

Instantiation of the `RandomForestClassifier`:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rand_clf = RandomForestClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', max_depth = 11, max_features = 'auto', min_samples_leaf = 2, min_samples_split = 3, n_estimators = 130)
rand_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I am stuck here:

```
y_pred = rand_clf.predict(X_test)
```

The error shown is:

```
ValueError: X has 29 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 30 features as input
```

How can I fix this? Otherwise, the `x_train` and `x_test` columns aren't equal.

Comment: Make sure that the same features in your training set are in your testing set. In other words, what's the difference between `x_train.columns` and `x_test.columns`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

> Shape of training set: (292, 30)
>
> The shape of the test set is: (91, 29)

The training and test set need to have the same number of features, either 29 or 30 (for both)